# Cant upload images in magento 1.8.1.0 after applying security patches

Tags: magento-1.8

I Cant upload images in Magento 1.8.1.0 after applying security patches. If I create new product and after entering the product details I go to images tab, I upload image after it stuck at uploading and shows an error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_File_Uploader' not found in
>   /chroot/mysite.com/html/releases/3/trunk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Uploader.php
>   on line 36

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied the patch SUPEE-8788, the Flash uploader has been replaced with a JS.

In Admin section: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml be sure that following line is there

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/uploader.js</script></action>
```

and in main template that following is not overwritten by another theme.

```
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</name>
```

if needed, remove

mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js

After this, flush your cache.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have checked them they are all there. I tried to delete flexuploader.js but still same

Answer (score 0):

If i use the google console i am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved finally. I just replaced lib/varien/file/uploader.php with fresh one